# Memory leaks happen when reconnecting in gRPC c++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, memory-leaks, grpc, grpc-c++

Windows, visual studio2017, C++, gRPC-1.40.0

The code is based on hello world, and the following process is added.

1. Input "x", the application will be terminated and the Protocol Buffers will be released.
2. Input something other than "x", create a channel and throw a request to the server.

Depending on the number of times enter other than "x", the amount of unreleased memory detected at the end of the application will increase.

-client-

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
struct cleanup_t
{
    ~cleanup_t() { if (IsDebuggerPresent()) _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks(); }
} cleanup;

#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <grpcpp/grpcpp.h>
#include <grpc/support/log.h>

#include "../common/helloworld.grpc.pb.h"

using grpc::Channel;
using grpc::ClientAsyncResponseReader;
using grpc::ClientContext;
using grpc::CompletionQueue;
using grpc::Status;
using helloworld::HelloRequest;
using helloworld::HelloReply;
using helloworld::Greeter;

class GreeterClient{
public:
    explicit GreeterClient(std::shared_ptr<Channel> channel)
        : stub_(Greeter::NewStub(channel)) {}

    std::string SayHello(const std::string& user){
        HelloRequest request;
        request.set_name(user);

        HelloReply reply;
        ClientContext context;

        Status status = stub_->SayHello(&context, request, &reply);

        if (status.ok()) {
            return reply.message();
        }
        else {
            std::cout << status.error_code() << ": " << status.error_message()  << std::endl;
            return "RPC failed";
        }
    }

private:
    std::unique_ptr<Greeter::Stub> stub_;
};

int main(int argc, char** argv){
    std::cout << "****************" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Start Client" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Finish：x" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "****************\n" << std::endl;

    bool exit = false;
    while ( !exit ){
        char buffer[128];
        printf(">");
        fgets(buffer, 128, stdin);

        if (strcmp(buffer, "x\n") == 0) {
            exit = true;
        }
        else{
            GreeterClient greeter(grpc::CreateChannel("localhost:50051", grpc::InsecureChannelCredentials()));
            std::string reply = greeter.SayHello("World");  // The actual RPC call!
            std::cout << "Greeter received: " << reply << std::endl;
        }
    }
    google::protobuf::ShutdownProtobufLibrary();
    return 0;
}
```

-server-

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <string>

#include <grpcpp/ext/proto_server_reflection_plugin.h>
#include <grpcpp/grpcpp.h>
#include <grpcpp/health_check_service_interface.h>

#ifdef BAZEL_BUILD
#include "examples/protos/helloworld.grpc.pb.h"
#else
#include "../common/helloworld.grpc.pb.h"
#endif

using grpc::Server;
using grpc::ServerBuilder;
using grpc::ServerContext;
using grpc::Status;
using helloworld::Greeter;
using helloworld::HelloReply;
using helloworld::HelloRequest;

class GreeterServiceImpl final : public Greeter::Service {
    Status SayHello(ServerContext* context, const HelloRequest* request,
        HelloReply* reply) override {
        std::string prefix("Hello ");
        reply->set_message(prefix + request->name());
        return Status::OK;
    }
};

void RunServer() {
    std::string server_address("0.0.0.0:50051");
    GreeterServiceImpl service;

    grpc::EnableDefaultHealthCheckService(true);
    grpc::reflection::InitProtoReflectionServerBuilderPlugin();
    ServerBuilder builder;

    builder.AddListeningPort(server_address, grpc::InsecureServerCredentials());

    builder.RegisterService(&service);

    std::unique_ptr<Server> server(builder.BuildAndStart());
    std::cout << "Server listening on " << server_address << std::endl;

    server->Wait();
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    RunServer();

    return 0;
}
```

Also added a process that can detect memory leaks on the server side, and when tested it, confirmed that the memory increased server too every time a connection was made.

---

Incidentally, you may think that should not create a `GreeterClient` class every time and throw requests, but the following code too will happen memory leaks.

-Procedure for Generating a Memory Leak-

1. Restart the server with the client running.
2. Input something other than "x".

Depending on the number of times above steps are performed, the amount of unreleased memory detected at the end of the application will increase.

-client-

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
struct cleanup_t
{
    ~cleanup_t() { if (IsDebuggerPresent()) _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks(); }
} cleanup;

#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <grpcpp/grpcpp.h>
#include <grpc/support/log.h>

#include "../common/helloworld.grpc.pb.h"

using grpc::Channel;
using grpc::ClientAsyncResponseReader;
using grpc::ClientContext;
using grpc::CompletionQueue;
using grpc::Status;
using helloworld::HelloRequest;
using helloworld::HelloReply;
using helloworld::Greeter;

class GreeterClient{
public:
    explicit GreeterClient(std::shared_ptr<Channel> channel)
        : stub_(Greeter::NewStub(channel)) {}

    std::string SayHello(const std::string& user){
        HelloRequest request;
        request.set_name(user);

        HelloReply reply;
        ClientContext context;

        Status status = stub_->SayHello(&context, request, &reply);

        if (status.ok()) {
            return reply.message();
        }
        else {
            std::cout << status.error_code() << ": " << status.error_message()  << std::endl;
            return "RPC failed";
        }
    }

private:
    std::unique_ptr<Greeter::Stub> stub_;
};

int main(int argc, char** argv){
    std::cout << "****************" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Start Client" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Finish：x" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "****************\n" << std::endl;

    GreeterClient greeter(grpc::CreateChannel("localhost:50051", grpc::InsecureChannelCredentials()));

    bool exit = false;
    while ( !exit ){
        char buffer[128];
        printf(">");
        fgets(buffer, 128, stdin);

        if (strcmp(buffer, "x\n") == 0) {
            exit = true;
        }
        else{                
            std::string reply = greeter.SayHello("World");  // The actual RPC call!
            std::cout << "Greeter received: " << reply << std::endl;
        }
    }
    google::protobuf::ShutdownProtobufLibrary();
    return 0;
}
```

I think the memory leak occurs every time reconnect and throw a request.

---

Memory leaks are occurring.
The attached image shows the result of monitoring the memory of the client in the following code with the performance monitor.
The memory monitoring started some time after startup.

```
int main(int argc, char** argv){
    std::cout << "****************" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Start Client" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Finish：x" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "****************\n" << std::endl;

    bool exit = false;
    while ( !exit ){
        char buffer[128];
        printf(">");
        fgets(buffer, 128, stdin);

        if (strcmp(buffer, "x\n") == 0) {
            exit = true;
        }
        else{
            while (true)
            {
                GreeterClient greeter(grpc::CreateChannel("localhost:50051", grpc::InsecureChannelCredentials()));
                std::string reply = greeter.SayHello("World");  // The actual RPC call!
                Sleep(1);
            }
        }
    }
    google::protobuf::ShutdownProtobufLibrary();
    return 0;
}
```

[image]
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks` could have false positives for static variables of gRPC since those are freed after the main() function. Since gRPC uses [MemorySanitizer](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/MemorySanitizer.html) to make sure to prevent gRPC from having memory leaks, you can use the same tool to check whether it's real memory leak.

Comment: Since the memory sanitizer is still in the testing stage in Visualstudio, I added the results of monitoring the memory with the performance monitor to see if memory leaks are occurring.
It looks like memory leaks are occurring.